Why does Brownian motion on a Riemannian manifold seem to no longer satisfy the constraint in its Ito formulation?
Suppose I have a manifold which is defined by the zeros of a vector-valued function $\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})$, with Jacobian matrix $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x})$ and an orthogonal projector onto the tangent space given by $\mathbf{\Pi} = \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{G}^T[\mathbf{G} \mathbf{G}^T]^{-1} \mathbf{G}.$
Then Brownian motion can be given by the Stratonovich SDE
$$ d\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\Pi} \circ d\mathbf{w}, \tag{1}$$
and then converting it to an Ito SDE gives
$$ d\mathbf{x} _i = \frac{1}{2} \sum_k \sum_j \mathbf{\Pi}^{k,j} \frac{\partial}{\partial q_k}
 \mathbf{\Pi}^{i,j} d t + (\mathbf{\Pi} \ d\mathbf{w})_i, \tag{2}$$
which using symmetry of the projection matrix, simplifies to:
$$ d\mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{\Pi}) \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\Pi} \, d t + \mathbf{\Pi} \, d\mathbf{w}, \tag{3} $$
where $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\Pi}$ is the matrix divergence of $\mathbf{\Pi}$.
But when I check that the solutions still lie on the manifold, ie. that $d\mathbf{g} = \mathbf{0}$, I get using Ito's Lemma that:
$$d \mathbf{g} = \mathbf{G} \, d \mathbf{x} + \frac{1}{2} \Delta \mathbf{g} \, d t, \tag{4}$$
where $\Delta \mathbf{g}$ is defined so that $(\Delta \mathbf{g})_i = \sum_j \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k } \mathbf{g}_i$.
Update - Correction:
Ito's Lemma when the matrix $\mathbf{\Pi}$ multiplies the noise in fact gives:
$$ \begin{align}
d \mathbf{g}_l &= (\mathbf{G} d \mathbf{x})_l + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{g}_l}{\partial \mathbf{x}_i \partial \mathbf{x}_j} [\sum_k \mathbf{\Pi}_{j,k} d \mathbf{w}_k] [\sum_k \mathbf{\Pi}_{i,k} d \mathbf{w}_k] \tag{4.1} \\ &= (\mathbf{G} d \mathbf{x})_l + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{g}_l}{\partial \mathbf{x}_i \partial \mathbf{x}_j} [\sum_k \mathbf{\Pi}_{j,k} \mathbf{\Pi}_{i,k} dt ] \\
&= (\mathbf{G} d \mathbf{x})_l + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{g}_l}{\partial \mathbf{x}_i \partial \mathbf{x}_j} \mathbf{\Pi}_{i,j} dt \\
&= (\mathbf{G} d \mathbf{x})_l + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{g}_l) \odot \mathbf{\Pi} dt
\end{align}$$
where $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{g}_l)$ is the Hessian matrix of $\mathbf{g}_l$ and $\odot$ is the Hadamard product.
This is harder to write in a vectorized form, so I will leave it written for each element $\mathbf{g}_l$ of $\mathbf{g}$.
However, I am unable to show that $(\mathbf{G} d \mathbf{x})_l + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{g}_l) \odot \mathbf{\Pi} = 0 \, \, \forall l$. Could anyone please help by letting me know where my mistake is?
Edit - Trying this on the unit circle:
I have that $$\mathbf{G} = \begin{bmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \end{bmatrix} \tag{6}$$ and therefore $$\mathbf{\Pi} = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}\begin{bmatrix} y^2 &-xy \\ -xy & x^2 \end{bmatrix}. \tag{6}$$
Then $$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\Pi} = \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} \begin{bmatrix} 2xy^2 + y^2(y^2 - x^2) \\ 2yx^2 + x^2(x^2 - y^2)\end{bmatrix}, \tag{7}$$
and $$ \mathbf{G} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\Pi} = \frac{2}{(x^2 +y^2)^2}  (4x^2 y^2 + x(y^4 - x^2 y^2) + y(x^4 - x^2 y^2)), \tag{8}$$
whereas $$\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{g}) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \tag{9}$$ and therefore $\sum_{i,j} \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{g}) \odot \mathbf{\Pi} = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}  \sum_{i,j}  \begin{bmatrix} 2y^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2x^2 \end{bmatrix}  = 2.$

This is kind of an interesting question. I tried to simplify the expressions by looking at an SDE on the unit circle embedded in $S^1$ but ran into similar "problems".  Can you check that case? Perhaps it turns out to be as follows: SDEs on manifolds are usually not formulated in terms of ambient space where something needs to be projected into the tangent space. The formulation is more modern in the sense that on $S^1$ we have an intrinsic one-dimensional process. One could look at it the way you are doing it but then one has to carefully define the scalar product with $dw,.$

I mean by this that the correct scalar product should be $dx=\Pi\color{red}{\circ}dw,.$ With that it is relatively easy to show $dg(x)=0,.$

Thanks for responding! I actually began by trying with the unit circle and ran into this issue, I tried to generalise it before posting so the question would be a bit more appealing. Do you mean by your second comment that you can show $d \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0}$ in that case?

We can show $d\mathbf{g(x)}=0$ in every case by the very definition of $\mathbf\Pi$ provided that we use Stratonovich calculus where simply $d\mathbf{g(x)}=\nabla\mathbf{g}\circ d\mathbf{x}=\nabla\mathbf{g\Pi}\circ d\mathbf{w},.$ Because $\mathbf{\Pi}$ projects to the tangent space and $\nabla\mathbf{g}$ is the normal vector that expression is zero. This is what makes me think that Stratonovich calculus is more appropriate. Of course the $d\mathbf{g(x)}$ is the same when we convert it to Ito (it acquires a drift) but the projection algebra isn't that obvious anymore.

Just thoughts I am having today. First time I ever think about this problem.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the projection algebra - when I convert using Ito's lemma don't I always have a kind of matrix multiplication with $\mathbf{\Pi}$ and the vector of $[d \mathbf{w}_1, ..., d \mathbf{w}_n]^T$ which is identical to the Stratonovich case, but with an additional drift?

Before we discuss what I meant by projection algebra and matrix multiplications your question about additional drift is astonishing. You wrote that down at the very beginning  of your post: It is the $dt$-term in $$d\mathbf{x} _i = \frac{1}{2} \sum_k \sum_j \mathbf{\Pi}^{k,j} \frac{\partial}{\partial q_k}
\mathbf{\Pi}^{i,j} d t + (\mathbf{\Pi} \ d\mathbf{w})_i,.$$ To have a  more fruitful discussion I suggest now that you simplify that whole question to the $S^1$ case to see some matrices in flesh and blood and that you number your equations.

Ok I may have time to write the question in the $S^1$ case later in the week - P.S. I think you misunderstood my previous comment, I didn't ask a question about the additional drift I just mentioned that the Ito conversion would contain an additional drift.

And why was there a question mark? (Let's postpone further discussions until you revised the question.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@KurtG. I've added equation numbers to the question and tried on the unit circle.
